# Visual Studio Extension Not Missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, publish, publishing

Visual studio 2013 update 3 is installed on my machine. Before the update I wrote a WCF service and I could publish the service with no problem. Now after the update I can public. When I go and publish I get a error.

[image]

So this did not make scene to me, but I followed the link and downloaded the executable and when I run it, it tells me that it is installed. Even when I go Tools>Extension and Updates it is there.

[image]

I open VS in administrator mode to see if I can Uninstall and re-install the extension but hen I click on the uninstall button nothing happens. Why is VS2013 doing this and how can I fix this?